# What part of the Android software stack handles commands through the headphone jack? (e.g. answering calls w/ a headset)

Tags: android

Where does Android deal with commands sent through headsets connected through a headphone jack? Specifically, for play/pause and answering calls? Is this buried in the OS or can it be accessed through an API?

Comment: Ever heard of the Square app? They're reading credit card info from a card reader attached to that same 3.5mm jack. I don't have any idea on how to do that though!

Comment: @Usagi - Seems like this was closed in error.  Anyway, the lowest level (things like activating pullup resistors and checking for switch closures, then deactivating them to save battery life) is handled in the kernel's device-specific code.  To find the mid-level android handling (at least in the generic case) you may need to download the entire repository (unfortunately huge) and do some full tree greps for likely terms.  Any app-accessible features / intents will be documented with other Android or Vendor APIs in the respective developer docs.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't really related to any of the android features or capabilities, it's just hardware related, a 3.5 doesn't have a limited and clearly defined number of connection, you can have a jack that is mono, stereo, with 3 channels or even other configurations.

as far as I know this kind of hardware ( the jack slot ) it's not even named in the list of requirements for getting the Google's commercial version of Android, so you can't even picture a clear set of devices based on the android version that you are targeting.

Comment: what do you mean with "number of connection"?

Comment: @gipi if you take a look at a male connector for the 3.5" jack, you can usually see some ring/s on the metal, they are the actual connection when the jack will be in place.

Comment: This is ignorant speculation, and in no way answers the question.  If you spend some time examining the android sources, you will see how this is handled on the specific devices targeted by that tree.